# What's the difference between magnetic susceptibility and permeability?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, material-science

From what I have read it seems magnetic susceptibility and magnetic permeability both represent the level of a material's magnetic response to an external field.

Fundamentally, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important equation here is the difference between $\mathbf H$ and $\mathbf B$ fields (using boldface for vectors):

$$\mathbf B = \mu_0(\mathbf H +\mathbf M),$$

where $\mathbf M$ is the magnetization of a sample under the applied magnetic field $\mathbf H$, $\mu_0$ is the permeability of vacuum and $\mathbf B$ you can see it as the real magnetic field in the room (both due to $\mathbf H$ and $\mathbf M$). The $\mathbf B$ field is the one that appears in the Maxwell law $\nabla \cdot \mathbf B =0$ (Gauss' law or no monopoles law).

For simplicity let us suppose that it is a 1D problem (or that every vector points in the same direction) so $$B=\mu_0 (H + M),  \tag{1}$$ (where italicized $B,H,M$ are the magnitudes of $\mathbf B$, $\mathbf H$ and $\mathbf M$).

The magnetic susceptibility $\chi$ tells you how the magnetization changes when you change $H$:
$$\chi=\frac{\mathrm{d} M}{\mathrm d H}.$$

IF and only IF $M$ is proportional to $H$ ($\chi$ is a constant of $H$, that is $M=\chi H$), then you can write equation ($1$) as

$$B=\mu_0(H+\chi H)=\mu H$$

where $\mu=\mu_0(1+\chi)$ is the permeability. This is often the case for paramagnetic/diamagnetic materials under small $H$.

Again when dealing with systems where everything is proportional and $\chi$ is a constant then $\chi$ and $\mu$ measure the same thing (with a difference of 1). In magnetic materials like iron or other ferromagnets this is not necessarily true.

Take away, $\chi$ is the relation between $H$ and $M$, and $\mu$ is the relation between $H$ and $B$ (when everything is proportional).

Answer (score 0):

There's a different definition for each one,

Magnetic permeability has to do with the property of a magnetic material to have its parts in a aligned magnetization

$$B=\mu H.$$

Magnetic susceptibility have to do with other properties of the material, as refractive index or absorption

$$ M= \chi H.$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on your answer? Is the only difference that they are used in different areas of physics?

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer is still relevant.

I'm just studying this myself and they are very similar.

$\mu _r = \chi + 1$

Where $\mu _r$ is **relative permeability** (The ratio of the permeability of a material to the permeability of free space $\mu _0$),

and $\chi$ is the **magnetic susceptibility**

That is their difference mathematically speaking but physically speaking, **magnetic susceptibility** measures the induced magnetic field as a factor of the applied magnetic field.

You might know of **diamagnetism, paramagnetism and ferromagnetism**

**Diamagnetic** materials repel, very weakly, applied magnetic fields and so their magnetic susceptibility is negative but  very tiny. For example, $\chi _{copper} = -10^{-5}$. So this figure tells us that the induced magnetic field inside copper is $-10^{-5}$ times the applied magnetic field.

Now speaking of **permeability**, this measures the **NET** magnetic field as a factor of the applied magnetic field. That is the difference, **magnetic susceptibility is to do with induced magnetic field but permeability is to do with net magnetic field (the vector sum of the applied and induced magnetic field)!!!**

So to finish it off, $\mu _{copper} = -10^{-5} + 1$ which is slightly less than 1 (from the equation above)

Note: above is the relative permeability of copper

Hope this helps Connor.